# Linux Kernel - ERROR: Failed to allocate 0x6b3c bytes below 0x1000000

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot, powerpc, device-tree

I'm including my rootfs (`CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE`) into my kernel, so the kernel has now a size of 17Mb:

```
$ ls -la uImage
-rw-r--r-- 1 kkr kkr 17669274 Dec  1 18:59 uImage
$ d2h 17669274
0x10D9C9A
```

Since it's compressed, it would occupied uncompressed 39Mb:

```
$ dd if=uImage of=uImage-x.gz bs=64 skip=1
$ file uImage-x.gz
uImage-x.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix
$ gunzip uImage-x.gz
$ ls -la uImage-x 
-rw-r--r-- 1 kkr kkr 39852288 Dec  1 19:18 uImage-x
$ d2h 39852288
0x2601900
```

Why cannot I start my kernel via uBoot with this commands?

```
=> setenv bootargs console=$consoledev,$baudrate $othbootargs

=> tftp 0x3000000 $bootfile
Speed: 100, half duplex
Using eTSEC1 device
TFTP from server 192.168.32.3; our IP address is 192.168.32.32
Filename 'uImage-powerpc'.
Load address: 0x3000000
Loading: #####################################################
done
Bytes transferred = 17669274 (10d9c9a hex)

=> tftp  0x2700000 $fdtfile;
Speed: 100, half duplex
Using eTSEC1 device
TFTP from server 192.168.32.3; our IP address is 192.168.32.32
Filename 'sat_92107.100.00C_p2020.dtb'.
Load address: 0x2700000
Loading: ##
done
Bytes transferred = 15164 (3b3c hex)

=> bootm 0x3000000 - 0x2700000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 03000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.0.0-AOA00.01-00662-g07ae
   Created:      2015-12-01  17:59:21 UTC
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    17669210 Bytes = 16.9 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02700000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x02700000
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
ERROR: Failed to allocate 0x6b3c bytes below 0x1000000.
device tree - allocation error
```

Since the kernel itself needs `0x10d9c9a` bytes (compressed) or `0x2601900` bytes (uncompressed) there is no chance to place the devicetree below `0x1000000`. Is this value (16Mb) configurable? Does my extracted kernel have be less than 16Mb otherwise?

Comment: "Embedded Modul TQMP2020" with 512Mb RAM - should be enough to load a 40Mb Ramdisk :o) I will go analyzing uboot, maybe I find out what's wrong...

Comment: Have you validated your methods by successfully booting with a smaller uImage file, containing a minimal initramfs?  *"should be enough to load a 40Mb Ramdisk"* -- Initramfs uses ramfs, which is not the same as ramdisk.

Comment: This answer may be helpful for the others even though I guess you have already figured out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this value is configurable in U-Boot by setting the environment variables `bootm_low` and `bootm_size` to hexadecimal values. In your case, it's `0x0` and `0x20000000`, respectively.

See section "Environment Variables" of the big README file in the U-Boot source tree.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar issue while trying to boot up FIT image within U-Boot 2022.10 on STM32MP15x features device.

```
   Loading Kernel Image
   Loading Ramdisk to cf8b0000, end cffff38d ... OK
ERROR: Failed to allocate 0x1e4ff bytes below 0xd0000000.
device tree - allocation error
FDT creation failed!
```

In my case the culprit was U-Boot config **CONFIG_LMB_MAX_REGIONS** defaulting to 8 whereas my DT defined 9 reserved-memory regions. U-Boot tried to relocate FDT from FIT image into RAM and failed, because it had already maximum number of memory regions allocated.